# Failing to parse into JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse the response from a `GET` request into a `JSONObject`. It keeps throwing an exception and I'm not sure what's causing it. JSONLint seems to think it's valid JSON string. Here's what I use:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Here's the code that obtained the String response:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
String result = "";
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(new URI(params[0]));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if (statusCode == 200) {
        in = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    }
}catch (IOException ex){
    Log.i("Error", ex.getMessage());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

If I copy the content of result to JSONLint it seems to be valid. If I validate it from the source [URL](https://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Localities.json) it also seems to be valid.

I'm at a loss here. Being a Java and Android noob I'm sure I have missed something very obvious.

Comment: post the json and how you get make your http request

Comment: I have added the code that executed the GET, but the JSON is quite lengthy. I'm not sure if I should post it here. If you click on that URL you will get the JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow wow,

It seem like your error when you trying to parse data.

Is your result is an String (I think you converted InputStream to String after got from Response)

I saw your data. It is an array.

```
httpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

String result = convertInputStreamToString(response.getEntity());

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = obj.getString("Name");
    //.... LocalityId or something...
}
```

Comment: Well duh! I guess it would've been handy if I actually looked at the string as well as validating it! Thank you, that did the trick!